# Keyword "typename" in Templates

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Following is the code and quote is from the *C++ Templates by Addison Wesley*:

```
template <typename T> 
  class MyClass { 
      typename T::SubType * ptr; 
      … 
  };
```

> Without typename, SubType would be considered a static member. Thus, it would be a concrete variable or object. As a result, the expression `T::SubType *ptr` would be a multiplication of the static SubType member of class T with ptr.

Now when I compile that code without the keyword 'typename', the error I get is this: `type ‘T’ is not derived from type ‘MyClass<T>’`.

Is the compiler recognizing 'T'?
If not, then shouldn't it be a *undefined reference* error?
If yes, then why is this an error?

Alright here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class MyClass 
{ 
     T::SubType * ptr; 
};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
~/Desktop/notes **g++ templates/programs/trial.cpp**
templates/programs/trial.cpp:6: error: type ‘T’ is not derived from type ‘MyClass<T>’
templates/programs/trial.cpp:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
```

Comment: [This site](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18) provides a useful explanation, and is a great resource to know about in general.

Comment: The code is incomplete, that error surely does not point to the `typename` line

Comment: @David and @Nawaz I have edited the first post showing the complete code and the exact error.

Comment: @Anisha: I saw the complete code now. So as I said before (in my answer), *sometimes compilers aren't smart enough to point out the error in template code accurately*. And that is exactly is the case now!

Comment: @Nawaz: So the reason that the author has written is correct or not?

Comment: @Anisha: If you're pointing to *Without typename, SubType would be considered a static member*, then that is correct.

Comment: @Nawaz: Of course I do understand that, but I think the author should have mentioned that an undefined reference error should be given to 'T'. and if there is no such error that means the compiler recognizes it?

Comment: @Anisha: How `T` is undefined reference?

Comment: @Nawaz: Well, my logic was that if the compiler "knew" what is 'T' then the keyword 'typename' wouldn't be required :) and if it didn't know it then it should be an "undef ref" :)

Comment: @Anisha: No. That is why I suggested you to read the articles first. Also read the FAQ link provided in the first comment.

Comment: @Anisha, `typename` appertains to the whole name `T::SubType` (saying that `SubType` is a type). It doesn't appertain to a qualifier of a qualified name. Qualifiers are implicitly known to be types or namespaces (this guarantee was accidentally missing in C++03, but is present in C++0x, so that in `T::foo::bar`, `foo` is implicitly known to be a type). In the case of `T`, the compiler can look it up in the template definition and find it is a type itself, too.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks for responding, so you mean to say that the compiler knows that 'T' is a type, and it just needs to know where is it defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way to get the same error from g++:

```
class Foo { static const int x = 0;};

template <typename T> class MyClass
{
     Foo::x * ptr;
};
```

and another:

```
class Foo { static const int x = 0;};

class MyClass
{
     Foo::x * ptr;
};
```

But you get a different error for this:

```
// class Foo { static const int x = 0;};

template <typename T> class MyClass
{
     Foo::x * ptr;
};
```

So:

1. Because T is a dependent type, g++ assumes that `T::SubType` is an object that will be defined by the time second-phase lookup occurs. That's as expected, and is the usual reason that `typename` is required here.
2. *Even if* `T::SubType` exists and is an object, the code is still bad, just like `Foo::x *ptr` is bad when `Foo::x` exists and is an object. I still don't understand what the error message is about - how would it help for `Foo` to be derived from `MyClass`? But the error message is nothing to do with templates.
3. "Undefined reference" is a linker error. Since this code fails to even compile, you shouldn't expect to see "undefined reference to T" anywhere.
4. I don't so far see how `Foo` even could be derived from `MyClass`. I tried the following to see whether it would give a clue to the meaning of the original message, but it fails because `MyClass` is an incomplete type, which doesn't tell me anything about what would happen if `Foo` were derived from `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
    class Foo: public MyClass { static const int x = 0;};
     Foo::x * ptr;
};
```

Comeau gives far more sensible error messages for all these cases - nothing about derived types, just says that `T::SubType` isn't a type. So explaining g++'s error message is going to take either knowledge or good guesses about g++ internals, and exactly where in the process of trying to parse your class template it finally gives up.

Answer (score 2):

> Without typename, SubType would be considered a static member. Thus, it would be a concrete variable or object. As a result, the expression T::SubType *ptr would be a multiplication of the static SubType member of class T with ptr.

This description is incorrect when applied to the example you give. In class bodies there can be no expressions, and no constructs are parsed as a multiplication. However, in the C++03 syntax, there is a construct that looks as follows

```
struct Base { int a; };
struct Derived : Base {
  Base::a; // access-declaration
};
```

This construct was deprecated in C++03 but still supported, and means the same as the following

```
struct Base { int a; };
struct Derived : Base {
  using Base::a; // using-declaration
};
```

Because you didn't tell the compiler that `T::SubType` is a type and hence tell the compiler that it should parse it as the type of a pointer declaration, the compiler assumed that `T::SubType` is the name in an access-declaration. Hence it expected a semicolon directly after it, and hence it expected that `T` is a *base class* of `MyClass<T>` (or that `MyClass<T>` is a *derived class* of `T`). The error message actually has it backwards:

```
 if (! UNIQUELY_DERIVED_FROM_P (IDENTIFIER_TYPE_VALUE (cname),
                                   ctype))
      {
        cp_error ("type `%T' is not derived from type `%T'",
                  IDENTIFIER_TYPE_VALUE (cname), ctype);
        ...
      }
```

While the macro says

```
 /* Nonzero iff TYPE is uniquely derived from PARENT.  Under MI, PARENT can
    be an ambiguous base class of TYPE, and this macro will be false.  */
 #define UNIQUELY_DERIVED_FROM_P(PARENT, TYPE) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Johannes, I have read your reply, and to make my question more clear, I tried this code `#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class MyClass 
{ 
     dd * ptr; 
};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
` In this case too, "dd" is an unknown to the compiler as was "T::subtype". Isn't it? but the error message is different `ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘dd’ with no type` That's what confuses and surprises me, if you think I am missing the point, the please enlighten. Also do you mean to say that the compiler is giving the wrong error message?

Comment: You mean that in the first case (the template object one) too, the compiler should give the error message "declaration with no type"?

Comment: @Anisha no the compiler is correct. What I said applies: "The error message has it backwards". Just swap base and derived and it is correct. If you say `dd *ptr`, then this cannot be a `BaseClass::Member;` (access-declaration). In an access declaration, the name specified must be qualified. As this is an unqualified name, it parses this as declaring the name `dd` (without a type). Other (valid) situations were unqualified named are declared that miss a decl specifier are `operator int();` (only the name "operator int" is present, and a function parameter list. No type syntactically).

Answer (score 0):

Because `T::SubType` is a dependent name, you need to tell the compiler that `SubType` is a *type* (not a static data member) by typing `typename` keyword.

Read about dependent name here:

- [Name binding and dependent names (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/name_binding.htm)
- [Dependent Names](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/427) (scroll down and read this section - better if you read the complete article)

---

EDIT:

As for your question (which you repeated in the comment):

I think what you've posted is not the complete code. So I cannot specifically comment on that. Also, sometimes compilers aren't smart enough to point out the error in *template* code accurately. So I suggested you to read about dependent name and when & why `typename` is required. Hopefully, after that you will not have any question!

Comment: My question was whether the compiler recognizes 'T'? If not, then shouldn't it be the "undefined reference" error?

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: I think what you've posted is not the complete code. So I cannot specifically comment on that. Also, sometimes compilers are not smart enough to point out the error in *template* code accurately. So I suggested you to read about dependent name and when & why `typename` is required first. Hopefully, after that you will not have any question!